# Concat 3 files with ffmpeg without losing quality

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to concat 3 files (avi) in FFMPEG without a loss of quality (if possible)

I use this `ffmpeg -i D:\Videos\Unedited\wsavi.avi -i D:\Videos\Unedited\wsavi_part2.avi -i D:\Videos\Unedited\wsavi_part3.avi -filter_complex "[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] [2:v:0] [2:a:0] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" D:\Videos\Unedited\avi.avi`

It works well, but I notice a significant loss in term of quality.

What can I do? Do I have to use `-crf` or `-q` in order to improve the quality?

Comment: This belongs to [su], not on [so]

Answer (score 1):

Outputting to AVI defaults to the MPEG-4 Part 2 video encoder named `mpeg4`. It's an old encoder so default quality is no longer acceptable.

- If you want MPEG-4 Part 2 video use `-q:v`/`-qscale:v` with a range of 2-5. Lower value is higher quality. `mpeg4` does not support `-crf`.
- Or use a different encoder such as `-c:v libx264`. See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264 Encoding](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265) for more info.
- Or output to a different container such as MP4 and it will use `libx264` by default (if it is supported by your `ffmpeg`).
- Or use the [concat demuxer](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) to concatenate your videos without re-encoding. The input videos must be the same format and have similar parameters.

Comment: Thanks , I don't understand a thing about the concat demuxer though. In the mylist.txt it says you have to put this 'file '/path/to/file1'
file '/path/to/file2'
file '/path/to/file3''

Comment: @VenlaFaxine See the concat demuxer link I provided in my answer.